# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class TestTarzan tried to access method 'void Tarzan.<init>(int, int)'

Tags: java

Absolute beginner in learning Java here. I'm trying to implement a class which accepts user input. Here is the code:

```
public class Tarzan {
    int total;
    int safe;

    Tarzan(int total, int safe) {
        this.total = total;
        this.safe = safe;
    }

    Tarzan() {
        total = 50;
        safe = 30;
    }

    int calculateResult() {
        int result = total - safe;
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestTarzan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter total: ");
        int t = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter safe: ");
        int s = sc.nextInt();

        Tarzan ta = new Tarzan(t, s);
        int res = ta.calculateResult();
        System.out.println(res);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Then when running `java .\TestTarzan.java`, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class TestTarzan tried to access method 'void Tarzan.<init>(int, int)' (TestTarzan is in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader @38c6f217; Tarzan is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at TestTarzan.main(TestTarzan.java:13)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: give access specifiers for your constructors and try . Like ```public Tarzan()``` , By default ```private``` is the access specifier .

Comment: Study about access modifiers in java

Comment: Please add the package of both ```Tarzan.java``` and ```TestTarzan.java```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the visibility of the constructor and methods to public, or to another visible access modifier

```
    public Tarzan(int total, int safe) {
        this.total = total;
        this.safe = safe;
    }

    public Tarzan() {
        total = 50;
        safe = 30;
    }
    public int calculateResult() {
        int result = total - safe;
        return result;
    }
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Can you explain why the access modifier needs to be changed? This is not the only solution.

Comment: Not working, same error

Comment: This isn't a complete answer. Look closely at the error message. Is it the _exact_ same error, or did you get a little further?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu also change the visibility of calculateResult

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that changing the access modifier of the constructor to `public` will fix this issue, it is important you learn an important lesson you are not getting from the comments or from the posted answer.

There are times when you want to control instance creation of an object and in those cases, it is perfectly fine to have access modification other than public. In this case, not having an access modifier in the constructor makes that method "package private." That means that only classes inside the same package (folder) can invoke this method. Even though the class itself is public, the constructor is not. Your Test class must be outside the package and that is why it cannot invoke the constructor of a class that the test class has visibility of.

The other problem you have with the `IllegalStateError` might be caused by not compiling all the classes you need to execute your program. You may want to try `javac {your_package}/*.java` to make sure all your classes under that package are compiled. Or better yet, use a build tool like Maven and build your classes that way. Remember, if the classes are in different folders, you might be partially compiling your classes if you exclude those packages when invoking your `javac` command.